# How do I migrate changes to my Azure SQL Server database from copy to production

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, visual-studio, azure

I'm trying to create an environment like the one in the pic where I have two Azure SQL Server databases, one for dev work and one for production. If I need to make a table change, column change, SP change, etc. Do I do it in the database copy? If yes, then how do I push those changes to production? Any tutorials or guides will be appreciated! I'm working mostly in a code-first approach with Entity Framework, but I also use SSMS frequently. Can this be scripted with TFS?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Entity Framework Code First, you should leverage the migrations functionality.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx

Comment: Just to add a little...Migrations are definitely the standard way to perform these kinds of updates when using code-first. I think of them as being like c# scripts using the code-first class structure. So you would make the migrations, test them on your dev database, and then once you have them working the way you want you can execute the migrations on the production database. I'm using Azure SQL database and I use auto-migration initialization code on my api app.

Comment: But what if I have to perform some task on the database that migrations doesn't support. For example I just added a spatial index to a DBGeography column, I don't think migrations supports this. Does it?

Comment: You can add those via codefirst as well. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh859721.aspx

Comment: Yes I'm aware I can add these via code first, but what about a spatial index on it? Can this be done with migrations? Or do I have to go to the database and do it manually?